# Can we put a same usecase more than twice in 1 usecase diagram

Tags: uml, modeling, use-case

There will be 4 roles, with 3 roles having a same use-case that is called `view campaign` and a use-case `view segment`.

Can we put a same use-case more than one time in the same use case diagram?

The idea is, in the same use case diagram, 3 `view campaign` use-case for the same  system.

Comment: Usually usecases appear only once, but can have multiple connections of all kind. It would be helpful if you put a picture in your question, that depicts how you think it should look like.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ okay sorry .. i will edit my question later or maybe in the next question i will include a picture

Comment: When asking about diagramming a picture is always better than 1000 words.

Comment: Adding the usecase diagram you roughly created in the question could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the same element more than once in a diagram. The UML specs do not forbid that and a few diagrams in the specs make use of this (really only in very rare and special cases).

On the other hand: if your use case diagrams resemble a spider web your design is likely broken. And if you tell that you have *3 view campaign use case* that's just nonsense. There is only one use case with that name. Use cases are unique in describing a single added value a system under consideration delivers to one of its actors.